# Dynamic data inside options list

Tags: javascript, react-native, dropdown

In my react native app I'm using [react-native-modal-dropdown](https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown), and it's working perfectly but the thing is that i want to set dynamic data inside the options list, it accept an array, and the data returned from my side returns an object that has an ID, a name, and a color, and it's stored inside the state, i only want to take names and put them inside the options, how can i do that? here is the code:

**Dropdown**

```
<ModalDropdown options={this.state.cars.name}/>
```

**Returned object**

```
state:{
    Cars:[
    {
     id: 1,
    Name: 'Mercedes',
    Color: 'Red'
    },
    {
     id: 2,
    Name: 'BMW',
    Color: 'Black'
    },
    {
     id: 3,
    Name: 'Toyota',
    Color: 'White'
    },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a `.map` to convert the objects array into an array of strings that contain only the names of the cars.

So doing something like this should work

```
<ModalDropdown options={this.state.cars.map(car => car.Name)}/>
```

Though you should note that you are referencing cars in two ways. Make sure to use the correct one. either `cars` or `Cars` depending on how you have it in your state.

```js
let state = {
    Cars:[
    {
     id: 1,
    Name: 'Mercedes',
    Color: 'Red'
    },
    {
     id: 2,
    Name: 'BMW',
    Color: 'Black'
    },
    {
     id: 3,
    Name: 'Toyota',
    Color: 'White'
    },
    ]
}

let carNames = state.Cars.map(car => car.Name);
console.log(carNames)
```

Comment: I’ve never used that dependency before. I would suggest looking at the docs and if you cannot figure it out ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't care about the ID then you can do it like so:

```
    const options = [{id: 1, name: "one"}, {id: 2, name: "two"}, {id: 3, name: "three"}].map(op => op.name);
    <ModalDropdown options={options}/>
```

Comment: If you're going to just add the name, then my answer is still going to work. Please try it out and update me